# Word/phrase for describing a relationship/association that could be productive and conterproductive

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

How to explain such a relationship/association (preferably not in the human context) :

> Approach A could be regarded as an innovative idea to leverage full potential of system B. In the reverse direction, it's possible to leverage concept A to attack to the system B.

Based on the answers of a similar [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/263521/word-phrase-for-a-feature-that-could-be-both-good-and-bad-for-something), such feature may be referred as *double-edged sword* or *mixed blessing*. Now, how can we refer to the relationship/association shaped around this feature?

I think **"A and B have a double-edged sword like relationship"** makes no sense. So, there is need to another word/phrase or even an idiom to describe that.

Comment: It's tempting to say 'relationship'.

Comment: More simply: "A and B have an **ambivalent** relationship/association/collaboration"

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between A and B [**cuts both ways**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+both+ways)

> ***[cut both ways](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cut-both-ways)*** - Having a mixed effect, to have advantages and disadvantages; to have two different effects at the same time, usually
> one good and one bad; To have both favorable and unfavorable results
> or implications; to affect both sides of an issue equally; to work both ways
>
> e.g. *The Internet cuts both ways – it not only opens borders, it draws boundaries between the people who have it and those who do not.*

You could also say (as @Graffito did), "A and B are **ambivalent** toward one another"

> [**Ambivalent**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/ambivalent) - Having mixed feelings or contradictory ideas about something or someone

Citations from the Oxford Dictionary and The Free Dictionary Idioms

Answer (score 0):

In this case A is the double edged sword.  B is the context in which A is double edged.  I don't see humans as entering into it.

> As far as B is concerned, A is a double edged sword.

would be one way to put it.